# The optimal constant for Burkholder-Davis-Gundy inequality

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

I have searched for some posts on math stack exchange, but I do not find a clear answer, can I have an explicit optimal constant for the BDG inequality $$\mathbb{E}\left[\int^T_0 \big|X(s)\big|^2ds\right]^{p/2}
   \leq C_p\mathbb{E}\left[\sup_{\tau\in [0,T]}\left|\int^\tau_0 X(s) dW_s \right|^p\right]?$$
In my case, I look for $C_p$ for $p=4$.

Comment: I find an answer in mathoverflow: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/98515/what-is-the-optimal-growth-of-the-constant-in-bdg?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C206.3352

Comment: @Enveador Thank you so much, I have read the post before, but all of them focused on the reverse direction of the inequality I want. However, I found a post here: https://almostsuremath.com/2020/06/22/pathwise-burkholder-davis-gundy-inequalities/ Corollary 4 there seems like what I want. Does it mean $C_p=(p/2)^{p/2}=4$ in my case?